# Scale multi page TIFF Image in java

Tags: java, image, scale, tiff, jai

I want to change the height of multi page TIFF image so I am using below code snippet to scale it. But It returns just first page from the tiff file , I guess it converts it to JPEG image. How to retain all pages of the file??

```
public static byte[] scale(byte[] fileData, int width, int height) {
  System.out.println("width:::"+width+"::::height:::"+height);
  ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
  ByteArrayOutputStream buffer=null;
  BufferedImage img=null;
  BufferedImage imageBuff=null;
  try {
    ImageInputStream imageStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData));

    java.util.Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageStream); 
    while(readers.hasNext()) {  
      ImageReader nextImageReader = readers.next();  
      nextImageReader.reset();  
    } 

    img = ImageIO.read(in);
    if(height == 0) {
      height = (width * img.getHeight())/ img.getWidth(); 
    }
    if(width == 0) {
      width = (height * img.getWidth())/ img.getHeight();
    }
    Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    imageBuff = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    imageBuff.getGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, new Color(0,0,0), null);

    buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ImageIO.write(imageBuff, "TIF", buffer);


  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
    if(img!=null){
      img.flush();
      img=null;
    }
    if(imageBuff!=null){
      imageBuff.flush();
      imageBuff=null;
    }

    if(buffer!=null){
      try {
        buffer.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    if(in!=null){
      try {
        in.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
public static byte[] resize(byte[] img,int height,int width) throws IOException {
        byte[] outimage = null;

        ImageReader reader=null;
        ImageWriter writer=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=null;
        ImageOutputStream ios=null;
        ImageInputStream imageStream=null;
        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(30000);
            ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);

            reader = getTiffImageReader();
            imageStream= ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(img));
            reader.setInput(imageStream);

            int pages = reader.getNumImages(true);

            Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriters = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF");
            writer = imageWriters.next();

            writer.setOutput(ios);
            ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            writeParam.setTilingMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DEFAULT);

            writer.prepareWriteSequence(reader.getStreamMetadata()); 

            for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
                //IIOImage iioImage = reader.readAll(i, null);
                BufferedImage bufimage=null;
                BufferedImage imageBuff=null;
                bufimage=reader.read(i);
                imageBuff=Thumbnails.of(bufimage).size(1200, 1200).asBufferedImage();
                IIOImage scalediioImage = new IIOImage(imageBuff, null, null);
                writer.writeToSequence(scalediioImage, writeParam);
                bufimage.flush();
                imageBuff.flush();
            }

            writer.endWriteSequence();
            outimage = baos.toByteArray();            


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
                if(imageStream!=null){
                    imageStream.close();
                    }
                if(ios!=null){
                    ios.flush();
                    ios.close();
                    }

                if(baos!=null){
                    baos.close();
                }
                if(reader!=null){
                     reader.dispose();
                }
                if(writer!=null){
                    writer.dispose();
                }
            }
        return outimage;
    }
```

Comment: You at least will need https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/ for that. It seems like you are asking for *multi-page* TIFF files, but I'm not sure whether ImageIO or even JAI can handle them at all...

Comment: I think it's strange that you get no output and no exceptions in your updated code, but it could be the `writer.setOutput(ios)` inside the loop that resets the writing process somehow. Only set output once, and do it before `writer.prepareWriteSequence()`.

Comment: Side note: `BufferedImage.flush()` is redundant here, unless you actually painted the images onto screen (ie. if only flushes native video RAM). The image will still be hold in Java heap memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIO.write(...)` will only ever write single stand-alone images. Writing multiple images to the same output stream does not remedy this. However the ImageIO package comes with full support for what you want, it just requires more code.

Obtain the proper `ImageWriter` for TIFF format, using :

```
ImageWriter writer =  ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();  // Assumes TIFF plugin installled
```

See the API docs for [ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getImageWritersByFormatName%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.

Then use [`writer.canWriteSequence()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#canWriteSequence%28%29) to tell if your `writer` instance supports writing sequences. It *should* return `true`for TIFF. If not, you need to find a different plugin.

Next, use [`writer.prepareWriteSequence(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#prepareWriteSequence%28javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata%29) to prepare your image sequence.

For each image (page) you want to append, use  [`writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(..., bufferedImage, null), ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#writeToSequence%28javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam%29) in a `for` loop.

Then finally, *outside* the `for` loop use [`writer.endWriteSequence()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#endWriteSequence%28%29) to end the image sequence.

Hope these pointers should get you going in the right direction.

Update: Here's a cleaned up and modified  version of your code that I *think* should work (I don't have and can't install JAI on my work laptop).

The important changes are removing the `writer.setOutput(ios)` from the loop (you should only set it once), and moving `writer.endWriteSequence()` oustide the loop.  I also removed the `BufferedImage` array, to avoid keeping all the images in memory, you might want to keep it for convenience.

Let me know if you still have trouble, and I'll see what I can do.

```
public static byte[] resize(byte[] img) throws IOException {
    byte[] outimage = null;

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(30000);
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);

        ImageReader reader = getTiffImageReader();
        ImageInputStream imageStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(img));
        reader.setInput(imageStream);

        int pages = reader.getNumImages(true);

        Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriters = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF");
        ImageWriter writer = imageWriters.next();

        writer.setOutput(ios);
        ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        writeParam.setTilingMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DEFAULT);

        writer.prepareWriteSequence(reader.getStreamMetadata()); // You want the stream metadata here

        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            IIOImage iioImage = reader.readAll(i, null); // Save some lines by using readAll

            BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) iioImage.getRenderedImage();

            // Modify image here...                

            iioImage.setRenderedImage(image);

            writer.writeToSequence(iioImage, writeParam);
        }

        writer.endWriteSequence(); // Crucial, must be done outside loop

        ios.flush();
        ios.close();

        outimage = baos.toByteArray();            
        baos.close();

        writer.dispose();
        reader.dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outimage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I tried using ImageWriter but I don't get any image back.I have posted updated code in question section.

Comment: @happy I updated the answer with modified code from your question.

Comment: your code is working properly but when I added the scaling code again I didn't got anything.Please check the updated code in question section.

Comment: When you say it works properly, you mean you got a fully working multi-page TIFF? If so, I have some ideas on how to remedy this. Try passing the metadata from `iioImage` to the `new IIOImage(...)` constructor.

Comment: yes I got all pages of the multipage image.but when I try to change the height of all the images in the tiff file I get a blank applet(which reads the byte array returned from the above method).