# Output image becomes black after conversion from FileInputStream to Image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to merge two TIFF images which are in form of FileInputStream into a single Tiff image. Although the image is getting merged the output file is coming up as Black. While comparing the original image and the converted image I could see that the bit depth of the converted image changes to 1. Could anybody provide a solution to this?
The code that I am using is:

```
public class MergerTiffUsingBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File imageFile1 = new File("D:/Software/pdfbox-1.3.1.jar/tiff/FLAG_T24.TIF");
        File imageFile2 = new File("D:/Software/pdfbox-1.3.1.jar/tiff/CCITT_3.TIF");
        try {
            FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(imageFile1);
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(imageFile2);
            List<BufferedImage> bufferedImages=new ArrayList<>();
            List<FileInputStream> inputStreams=new ArrayList<>();
            inputStreams.add(fis1);
            inputStreams.add(fis2);
            Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tiff");
            ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();

            for(FileInputStream inputStream:inputStreams){
                ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(inputStream);
                reader.setInput(iis);
                ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
                Image image = reader.read(0, param);

                BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/Software/pdfbox-1.3.1.jar/tiff/MergedTiff.TIF");
                BufferedImage binarized = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
                ImageIO.write(binarized, "tiff", out);
                bufferedImages.add(bufferedImage);
            }
            System.out.println(bufferedImages.size());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why null is being passed as an argument to getWidth() and getHeight() in the following line of your code: **BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);** .

Comment: image.getWidth accepts ImageObserver interface as an input but here it is not applicable (I am guessing), that is why used null.

Comment: The `null` argument is merely an artifact of the "old" image handling. It should be an ImageObserver. If you have none, you should use a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html to wait until the images are loaded. In any case: You are creating an `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`, so why do you expect a bit depth that is *different* from 1? This is *binary*. 0 or 1. Try an `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` instead.

Comment: You need to close your `FileOutputStreams`. Otherwise at best you are leaking file descriptors, and possibly losing data.

Comment: I tried closing the FileOutputStream but still getting a black output. I also changed BufferImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY to TYPE_INT_RGB but without any luck. Can you please suggest possible amendments to the code to accomodate the ImageObserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused about how to copy image data. Simply creating a new, blank image, by passing the dimensions of another image, will not copy it... So a fully black image is what I would expect after running your code.

Replace your for loop with something like this:

```
for (FileInputStream inputStream : inputStreams) {
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(inputStream);
    reader.setInput(iis);

    BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, null); // a) BufferedImage is returned! b) null param is fine!

    BufferedImage binarized = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

    // The following 7 lines is the important part you were missing:
    Graphics2D g = binarized.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    finally {
        g.dispose();
    }

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/Software/pdfbox-1.3.1.jar/tiff/MergedTiff.TIF");

    ImageIO.write(binarized, "tiff", out); // You probably want to check return value (true/false)!

    bufferedImages.add(image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks HaraldK, the solution did work. But when I am trying to merge 2 input stream to create a single image the second image is coming up as black. Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: How do you "merge 2 input stream to create a single image"? Are you trying to create a multipage TIFF from two images?

Comment: yes exactly. but i don't have the TIFF images but fileinputstream of those images. Is there any way to do this? I am able to create two TIFF images from the inputstreams and save them to a outputstream and then merge them but I want to avoid the saving of the images and then merging.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22934824/1428606 for how to write multi page tiff